# Is there any Customizable Sniff Properties for classes/traits/interfaces?

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer, phpcs

is there any Customizable Sniff Properties for classes/traits/interfaces to do the followings;

- not allow a blank line before the first content
- One blank line after the last content

I am expecting a rule for something like this.

example

> Valid code

```
Class Example()
{
  /** Content */

}
```

> Invalid Code: After the content it does not have a blank line & before the content there is a space allowed

```
Class Example()
{
 
 /** Content */
}
```

Comment: Do I need to write a new rule or is there any way to enable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer Squiz.WhiteSpace.FunctionSpacing sniff.

Not completely it matches, but as most classes will have functions at the end, the "One line after last" can be enforced and if the class content starts with a function, the "No blank line before first" as well.

Refererance: https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Customisable-Sniff-Properties#squizwhitespacefunctionspacing

found this solution form different source